aws rds version
Is it possible to get aws rds version?
I know for Aws rds Aurora version
select aurora_version();
 aurora_version 
----------------
 16.3.0
(1 row)

 select version();
                                                   version                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 16.3 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 9.5.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

 SHOW server_version
 server_version 
----------------
 16.3
(1 row)

but I want to know the rds version().
and anyone know where aurora_version() is stored in catalog?
My main concern is to distinguish between the 2 instance aurora and rds. One instance create with aurora PostgreSQL and other one normal RDS PostgreSQL, by running select aurora_version(); I can say that this aurora instance on success!. like I want to confirm RDS(not aurora) instance.

tyr this aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier your-instance-identifier --query 'DBInstances[0].EngineVersion'  but the thing is there is nothing like RDS version its only database versions that rds holds

I want to run the command once i connect to Database. i am connecting using public URL

but there is nothing like RDS version  if you are running diffrent RDS then arurora they have different comands to get version fo that db, is that what you want?? and one more thing aurora_version() is not stored in catalog it is implimented within the aurora engine

My main concern is to distinguish between the 2 instance,  one instance create with aurora PostgreSQL and other one normal, by running above command i can say that this aurora instance if works!. like I want to confirm its  RDS(not aurora) instance.

SELECT version(); ?

no, @FrankHeikens that wont help me, select version(); SHOW server_version

what do you mean by normal RDS, i think you need bit of explanation with example. like how you prvisoned RDS with aurora and how did you provision for normal and after we are clear we can help you

@0xn0b174 My main concern is to distinguish between the 2 instance aurora and rds, one instance create with aurora PostgreSQL and other one normal RDS PostgreSQL, by running select aurora_version(); I can say that this aurora instance on success!. like I want to confirm RDS(not aurora) instance.

then you @FrankHeikens answer is  the right answer you can  execute both the command in instance if it succeds then its related to its specific version, you can write script to check that

@0xn0b174 SELECT version(); work on aws rds postgresql also, with this command can not find out.

i had to answer you in answer section becasue OP was deniying the command SELECT version(); not getting the postgres version and i could not paste the proof in comment.
i created posgres rds and connected to it and run the command,
so here is the proof, here you go:


Thank you for your answer, but this not what i am looking, I know that i can run select version() or show server_version in aws rds. But i cant run select aurora_version();. im asking that any command to find rds version? if you try select aurora_version it fails in rds instance.

just tell me one thing , will  sudo apt get update run in windows cmd?? if it does so will your aruora_version command will run in RDS becasue its not the same they are named different becasue they are different and you cannot run ones command on another.

Let's focus on addressing your concern which is to distinguish between the 2 instance Aurora Postgres and RDS Postgres since there is nothing like rds_version
do $$
declare
v_ver varchar(10);
begin
select aurora_version() into v_ver; 
raise notice '%',v_ver;
exception 
    when others then
    raise notice 'It''s RDS Postgres';
end;
$$;

Above script will always give result for Aurora postgres and will always fail for RDS(will always execute exception block).
